# How to prevent the same network being recognized as a new one?

Tags: networking, windows-7

Every once in a while a Windows 7 machine I administrate creates a new network profile. It started off being on 'Network' and by now it's on 'Network 5'. It is not on a domain, and it's unclear to me what relevant network characteristics would change at random, except that internet might be out now and then.

How do I stop it from happening (without introducing a DC)? Even using a static IP didn't.

One solution I'd be interested in, would be to disable *Network Location Awareness* for one specific adapter and have it permanently assigned to a certain network, if that's possible. I only found ways to fix a network to a profile (private/public), but nothing that works at the adapter level.

Answer (score 0):

Please read that for NLA. You need to make sure step 1 is correct.

> Step 1 – Domain Determination
>
> In all cases, detection starts the same way that it does in Windows
>   XP. If the Connection Specific DNS Name matches the
>   “HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group
>   Policy\History\NetworkName” registry key then the machine will attempt
>   to contact a Domain Controller via LDAP. If both these steps succeed,
>   you will get the Domain profile. It is important to note that if the
>   steps succeed, **processing stops here**. This allows you to roam across
>   multiple access points in the same domain without having to stop and
>   identify each of them individually. Step 2 – Network Identification
>
> **If the above steps are complete and a match to the domain was not
>   found, NLA will evaluate the network characteristics to see if it can
>   identify a match.**

From [Network Location Awareness (NLA) and how it relates to Windows Firewall Profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles/)

Comment: I do not have a domain controller. The characteristics of the network are not changing as far as I can tell.